# Upgrade to mysql 5.7 from 5.5, MyISAM to InnoDB, LEFT JOIN and NULL issue

Tags: php, mysql, join, innodb, mysql-5.7

I've recently updated a database from MySQL 5.5 with MyISAM tables to MySQL 5.7 InnoDB tables. Most things are working absolutely fine, but there's a few particular queries that are giving strange results.

Background: A suggestion is first approved and can then be voted on. A suggestion is visible to only the suggester before it is approved.

Query:

```
SELECT description, suggested_by, voted, votes
FROM shop_suggestions s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT suggestion, 1 AS voted FROM shop_suggestion_votes WHERE student = 60910) AS voted ON (voted.suggestion = s.id)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT suggestion, COUNT(student) AS votes FROM shop_suggestion_votes GROUP BY suggestion) AS votes ON (votes.suggestion = s.id)
WHERE  approved > 0 OR suggested_by = 60910 ORDER BY votes
```

- The first join
  (LEFT) is to see if the voter has already voted on this
- The second
  join (LEFT) is to see how many votes there are in total

What's really strange, is that when the `ORDER BY votes` part is there, the voted value is always 1, whereas if it's left off, it's NULL as expected when somebody hasn't voted.

This behaviour is different to what it was before my upgrade, where the query worked perfectly. I'm assuming there's some kind of logic error somewhere, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Hmmm . . . could the data have changed?  An `order by` should not change the result sets being returned, so perhaps you are just not looking at all the results.

Comment: You have a typo in your query `FROM shop_suggestion_votes AND voter = 60910`

Comment: @GordonLinoff no - the data is exactly the same. The fact that the ORDER BY makes the difference is most confusing. I guess I could remove that, and add the whole query as a sub query, then set the order there, but that doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, I tried to simplify the query, but the issue is not typos - the query works, but gives unexpected results. I'll update the query with working SQL now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks all right to me.  But, you can simplify it:

```
SELECT description, suggested_by, voted, votes
FROM shop_suggestions s LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT suggestion, COUNT(student) as votes,
             MAX(student = 60910) as voted
      FROM shop_suggestion_votes
      GROUP BY suggestion
     ) votes
     ON (votes.suggestion = s.id)
WHERE approved > 0 OR suggested_by = 60910
ORDER BY votes;
```

If I had to speculate on the actual problem, I would guess that you over-simplified the query and have removed the offending problem.  Some commonly (mis)used features of MySQL are documented not to always work, but they are used anyway.  One that comes to mind is the use of columns in a `select` that are not in a `group by`.  Another is the order of evaluation of expressions that use variables.  Your code has neither of these, but perhaps your original code has something suspicious.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good approach - I like the use of MAX, very clever. The code in my question is now exactly what I've run in the database though - with the ORDER BY I get 1s for the voted, without I get NULLs. If you've got any more insights to help me understand the original issue that would be amazing - however I will refactor the query to match your suggestion anyway as it's clearly a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You found a bug where the optimizer takes a literal directly before knowing if the `left join` has any results. It is a derivate of a known bug, 
[Bug #77707 Right outer join return wrong result when literal expression involved](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77707) (the `left join`-version got merged with this).

It was supposedly fixed in [5.7.8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-8.html),

> Incorrect results could be produced tor views and derived tables on the inner side of an outer join and from which non-nullable expressions such as literals were selected. (Bug #73953, Bug #20841369, Bug #67014, Bug #15967464, Bug #65936, Bug #14358878, Bug #67300, Bug #15936817, Bug #76327, Bug #20708288)

Since the (new) filesort has its own optimizer, it seems the bug still persists there and resurfaces when using `order by` (before, it happened with or without ordering).

Send a bug report.

To make your query work, you can (apart from Gordons rewritten code) trick mysql into evaluating something (and thus not optimizing the literal away) by using e.g.

```sql
...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT suggestion, 
           case when student = student then 1 else null end AS voted 
           FROM shop_suggestion_votes WHERE student = 60910) AS voted 
...
```